Do I own and retain all rights (copyright) to all the content posted on my profile page?
Does the 'public Network' include content on the profile page such as the profile picture and display name?
Does the answer to Do I have to give attribution to SO when using my own content elsewhere? also apply to all the content posted on my profile page?
Further clarification:
Just as @Joachim mentioned, this is specifically about the content on the user profile page and not about Q&A as discussed on the hyperlinked post.
I need a specific, explicit answer for the licensing/copyright/ownership terms for the content on the profile page. I hope this clarifies the distinction between my post and the other hyperlinked one.
If it is 100% certain that my question is within the scope of the hyperlinked post, I'm happy for this post to be closed.

@Makyen This is specifically about the user profile page and About section, I presume, which, understandably, appears different from other written contributions. (Though I believe I've seen this question before..)

@Joachim So? The answer on that duplicate, which is linked in the question, is completely about user-contributed content. How is user-contributed content that's in the user's profile page not user-contributed content? While answers are used as an example in the question, the question and answer are about user-contributed content, not restricted to user-contributed content located on a specific page.

@JCr No, your edit doesn't distinguish this question from that one. There is no distinction. The question and answer you've linked in the question are clearly about user-contributed content, not content that's on one page or another.

In addition, the Terms of Service (ToS) is clear as to it being all content contributed by users. It speaks only about "Subscriber Content", "all content", etc. on the public network without treating the content you've contributed on a certain pages in a special manner. The ToS being clear doesn't in itself mean the other question is a duplicate. It just contributes to me wondering where the idea came from that the user-contributed content in your profile (other than PII) would have a different legal status. I am interested in knowing, as something at least left open that possibility to you.

@Makyen Like I said, because it appears to be different, and I can understand (new) users are confused by it.

You remain the copyright holder and may republish your posts and any other information that you have created under any licence you like.
What you've given to Stack Exchange is simply the irrevocable right to display your posts.
